# C# check if strictly all characters in one string exist in another (NO LINQ)

Tags: c#, string, loops, substring

I have a dictionary and I want to remove all the keys that in some way contain all the characters of a given word. For example, if the given word is corrupt, all key/pair values with keys such as "cor rupt", "co2rrupt", "ruptcor" should be removed.

So far I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why.

```
        static Dictionary<string,double> Dict2(){
        var dict = new Dictionary < string, double > ();
        dict.Add("rupt cor0",1);
        dict.Add("cor rupt1", 33);
        dict.Add(" 4 cor ru pt4", 10752);
        dict.Add("ted45", 6.878);
        dict.Add("key2", 0.0033482143);

        var word = "corrupt";

        Console.WriteLine("This is the origina dictionary");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dict)
        {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key {kvp.Key}: Value={kvp.Value}");
        }


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in dict)
        {
            
            foreach (char character in word)
            {
                if (entry.Key.Contains(character))
                {
                    dict.Remove(entry.Key);
                }
                
            }
        
        }
```

This code should remove the first 3 pairs, but when I re-print the dict after I have removed the pairs, it only contains key2:0.0033482143.

I would like a way that does not use LINQ.

Comment: That restriction seems a bit arbitrary. Why no LINQ? That's "just" a bunch of extension methods that make life so much easier. You _could_ re-implement all of them yourself... Anyways, I'd probably start with something like having the "searchword" as a list of characters. Then go through each character of the key, check if it's `[a-zA-Z]` and remove the first occurence of it from the list. If the list is empty and there are still such characters in the key, it is "false". Only if at end of key the list is empty, it is "true". (reset list after every key!)

Comment: @Corak Probably homework or something, without LINQ the teachers probably will have a bit more idea about the way of thinking of a student.

Comment: It is just an exercise of implementing this without LINQ and other libraries.

Comment: _" it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why."_ Your last `foreach` will check if the `Key` from the dictionary contains 1 character from `word` and if yes, it will remove the whole entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to loop through all the keys, and if the key length is at least as long as the word, loop through each character of the word and remove it from the key. Then if we've removed all the characters, then this key should be removed because it contained all the characters. This requires creating a temporary variable to store the key and word values, since we don't want to modify the originals.

```
var keysToRemove = new List<string>();

foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{
    if (key.Length < word.Length) continue;

    var tmpKey = key;
    var tmpWord = word;

    foreach (var chr in word)
    {
        var keyIndex = tmpKey.IndexOf(chr);
        if (keyIndex < 0) break;
        tmpKey = tmpKey.Remove(keyIndex, 1);
        tmpWord = tmpWord.Remove(0, 1);
    }

    if (tmpWord.Length == 0) keysToRemove.Add(key);
}

foreach (var keyToRemove in keysToRemove)
{
    dict.Remove(keyToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4th element should be removed due to the matching **t** in corrup**t** and **t**ed45
Also, you should iterate in reverse order over your list you're modifying.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict.Add("rupt cor0", 1);
dict.Add("cor rupt1", 33);
dict.Add(" 4 cor ru pt4", 10752);
dict.Add("ted45", 6.878);
dict.Add("key2", 0.0033482143);

var word = "corrupt";

Console.WriteLine("This is the origina dictionary");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key {kvp.Key}: Value={kvp.Value}");
}


for (int i = dict.Keys.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var entry = dict.ElementAt(i);

    foreach (char character in word)
    {
        if (entry.Key.Contains(character))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Entry `{entry.Key}` contains `{character}`. Remove");

            dict.Remove(entry.Key);
            break;
        }

    }
}

Console.WriteLine("This is the modified dictionary");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key {kvp.Key}: Value={kvp.Value}");
}
```

Comment: `ted45` does not contain all the characters of `corrupt`, yet it was removed.

Comment: ElementAt is a LINQ method, but thanks for your help!